# How to inject $http service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm new to angular.js. But I would like to write code with some unit tests.
How can I inject and test $http get method in karma/jasmine?
Code below doesn't seem to work. I'm using Angular 1.4.7.

#### app.js

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('myctrl',function($scope,$http){

var vm = this;    
vm.mode = 'fun';

$http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
.success(function(response) {
    $scope.data= response.records;
    $scope.message  = 'ok'
});

vm.setDescription = function(age){
    if(age <= 10){
        vm.description = 'child';
    } else if(age > 10 && age < 18){
        vm.description = 'teen';
    } else if(age >= 18){
         vm.description = 'adultt';
    }
}
});
```

#### app.specs.js

```
describe('Controllers', function(){ //describe your object type

var scope
var $http, $q;

beforeEach(module('MyApp')); //load module

beforeEach(inject(function(_$http_, _$q_) {
      $http = _$http_;
      $q = _$q_;
}));

describe('myctrl',function(){ //describe your app name

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){ //instantiate controller using $controller service

        scope = $rootScope.$new
        myctrl = $controller('myctrl',{$scope: scope, $http: $http});

    }));


    it('Message should be ok', function(){  //write tests
        expect(scope.messge).toBe('ok'); //pass
    });

});       

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $httpBackend to mock HTTP calls. Read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)